# Using regular profiles in RDS environment with user profile disks (Windows Server 2016)

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016, rds

I deployed an RDS farm with user profile disks that are stored on a cluster shared volume so that .vhdx-files are shared among all servers. It works well except one thing: I can't connect to more than one server with the same account simaltenously. It makes sense since .vhdx-file is locked by the first server I connected to.

But this is very inconvenient if I want to connect to multiple servers as administrator, it means I have to create a separate admin account for each server. It also appeared that UPDs are used not only for RD sessions, but for login from the real console as well. Is this how it supposed to work? Can I at least use local Administrator account with a regular profile and not UPD?

Comment: Yes. That is how it works. No. There is nothing you can do.

Comment: Also, it doesn't prevent you from logging in to additional servers with the same account. It just prevents your profile from loading and you get an empty temporary profile.